# Root finding with quadrature

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, root-finding

I have a problem with root finding and am having difficulty in getting it to work in this instance.

Some complicated function I need.

```
f[x_, lambda_, alpha_, beta_, mu_] = 
   Module[{gamma}, 
     gamma = Sqrt[alpha^2 - beta^2]; 
     (gamma^(2*lambda)/((2*alpha)^(lambda - 1/2)*Sqrt[Pi]*Gamma[lambda]))*
      Abs[x - mu]^(lambda - 1/2)*
      BesselK[lambda - 1/2, alpha Abs[x - mu]] E^(beta (x - mu))
   ];
```

A function I want to find the root of is defined as the integral of this function so I use quadrature:

```
F[x_, lambda_, alpha_, beta_, mu_] := 
    NIntegrate[f[t, lambda, alpha, beta, mu], {t, 0, x}];
```

Now the problem, mathematica has difficulty solving the roots of this equation,

```
Q[u_, lambda_, alpha_, beta_, mu_] := 
    x /. FindRoot[F[x, lambda, alpha, beta, mu] == u, {x, 1}]
```

Does anybody know why? The integral is defined at all points in R. f here is a density function and F its CDF.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Try using `:=` instead of `=` in the definition of `f`.` and see if that helps.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, then.

Comment: @Verbeia if you do, I'll delete mine. Feel free to use my results

Comment: @belisarius ok, done - I've added your graphic to mine. Thanks!

Comment: @rcollyer We should post an AWK or Perl script for converting questions using greek letters in our Tool Bag question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `:=` instead of `=` in the definition of `f` and see if that helps.

Incidentally when you use this `SetDelayed` syntax, you don't need semicolons to suppress output, because it doesn't immediately create output.

Here is some sample output, courtesy of belisarius and WReach:

[image]

Comment: You can eliminate the "not a valid limit" warning message by redefining `F`: `Clear@F; F[x_?NumericQ, ...] := ...`

Comment: @WReach The fault was mine and not Verbeia's. I was too lazy to correct a non-critical bug. (My original answer is now deleted because the main idea was posted by Verbeia in a comment and then mutated into this answer)

Comment: @Verbeia New image here (with the `?NumericQ` test) http://i.stack.imgur.com/WfjCu.png

Comment: belisarius - I'm at work, between meetings - feel free to edit my answer